# Prove that : $|f_{n}(x)|≤f_{n}(0)≤\frac{1}{e}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let :

$$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{1-n^{2}|x|^{2}}},|nx|<1\\0,|nx|≥1\end{cases}$$

Prove that :

$$|f_{n}(x)|≤f_{n}(0)≤\frac{1}{e}$$

My try  :

Since :

$$f_{n}(0)=\frac{1}{e}$$

Clearly but how

$$|f_{n}(x)|≤f_{n}(0)$$

I don't have any method

I have already to see your solution

Comment: Prove that $x\mapsto e^{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$ defined on $[-1,1]$ has its maximum at $x=0$.

Comment: @Surb Do you mean "defined on $(-1, 1)$"?

Answer (score 1):

On $(0,\frac  1 n) $ we have $0 \leq 1-n^{2}x^{2} \leq 1$. Hence $f_n(x) \leq e^{-1}=f_n(0)$. For $x \geq \frac  1n$ the inequality is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

1)$z:=1-(nx)^2$, $|nx|<1,$
 i.e. $z\in (0,1]$;

$0< e^{-1/z}\le e^{-1}$, i.e.

$0<f_n(x)\le e^{-1}$ for $|nx| <1$.

2) $f_n(x)=0$ for $|nx| \ge1$.

3) Combining :

$0\le f_n(x) \le f_n(0)=e^{-1}$.